# Avro data serialization with Python map reduce

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, avro

I have avro data present into hdfs files system. I want to read those avro data using python map reduce. I know that if I have to use java then we can use AvroMapper and AvroReducer but using python i am not too sure.

Anyone here has worked upon this or any suggestion would be great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [Pydoop](http://crs4.github.io/pydoop) >= 1.0.0-rc2. Here is how the color count example looks like:

```python
from collections import Counter

import pydoop.mapreduce.api as api
import pydoop.mapreduce.pipes as pp
from pydoop.avrolib import AvroContext

class Mapper(api.Mapper):

    def map(self, ctx):
        user = ctx.value
        color = user['favorite_color']
        if color is not None:
            ctx.emit(user['office'], Counter({color: 1}))

class Reducer(api.Reducer):

    def reduce(self, ctx):
        s = sum(ctx.values, Counter())
        ctx.emit('', {'office': ctx.key, 'counts': s})

def __main__():
    factory = pp.Factory(mapper_class=Mapper, reducer_class=Reducer)
    pp.run_task(factory, private_encoding=True, context_class=AvroContext)
```

To run the application:

```bash
export STATS_SCHEMA=$(cat stats.avsc)
pydoop submit \
  -D pydoop.mapreduce.avro.value.output.schema="${STATS_SCHEMA}" \
  --avro-input v --avro-output v \
  --upload-file-to-cache color_count.py --mrv2 \
  color_count input output
```

See the [Pydoop Avro docs](http://crs4.github.io/pydoop/examples/avro.html) for details.